# STM32CubeIDE: How to update Includes Folder in Project Explorer

Tags: stm32cubeide, file-inclusion

I have a question about how to update Includes folder in a downloaded example from STM32 CubeMX.

Currently, I am working with LoRaWAN_End_Node example downloaded from STM32 CubeMX for the board Nucleo-WL55JC1. Based on that example, I want to add some of my files (both header and source files).

I want to ask how do I update Includes folder (in Project Explore) when I put new header files in the Inc directory (Inc is not shown in the Project Explorer tab).

I hope to have help from people in the community.
[image]

Thank you, Huy Nguyen.

Comment: I added the header files to the Inc directory already but the Includes in STM32CubeIDE has not been updated yet (I dont know how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you asked, but I hope it may help someone

First, I think that you need to build the solution in orded to the files to be added

What I usually do to add header (and source files) is to create a new folder, I add that folder path into the project (project properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and symbols -> includes -> add), inside that folder I add the Inc and Src folders (Add them inside the STM32CubeIDE), and add those as source Locations (project properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and symbols -> Source Locations -> add folder)
Then copy the headers and source files that you might need (whit the windows explorer), finally build the project, when you build it the files will be added to the project.

Comment: Sorry for not updating the situation. I figured out the way to overcome the bigger issue without coming to this problem.
Thank you very much for your comment.